# Why does a water drop on a hot plate at 150°C evaporate faster than on a plate at 200°C?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, temperature, evaporation

I recently read that:

> A drop of water landing on a hot plate at 150°C (300°F) evaporates in a few seconds. A drop of water landing on a hot plate at 200°C (400°F) survives a whole minute.

How would you explain this observation using physics principles?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That is the [Leidenfrost effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect).

If the surface is hot enough, a layer of vapor exists between the hot surface and the droplet, insulating the droplet from the full heat.

The droplet levitates above the hot surface.

Comment: This is amazing!